# StreamReader only displaying last item in selected file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, streamreader

I am very new to this and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

It only processes and displays one line of results, but I need it to process and display everything in the file. The files that can be selected are `.txt` files, those have multiple students names along with 3 test scores for the program to calculate and display an average and a letter grade, which it does perfectly, but only for one student for each file, when the files have probably 10 names in each.

The code in question is:

```cs
//VARIABLES
string gLetter = null, studentName = null;
int test1 = 0, test2 = 0, test3 = 0, avg = 0;

private void processButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        getdata();
        calculatedata();
        displaydata();
        resetitems();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}

private void getdata()
{
    try
    {

        StreamReader inputFile;
       
        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            inputFile = File.OpenText(openFile.FileName);
            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                studentName = inputFile.ReadLine();
                test1 = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                test2 = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                test3 = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}

private void calculatedata()
{
    try
    {
        //calc avg
        avg = (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3;
        
        //find gLetter
        if (avg >= 90)
            gLetter = "A";
        else if (avg >= 80)
            gLetter = "B";
        else if (avg >= 70)
            gLetter = "C";
        else if (avg >= 60)
            gLetter = "D";
        else if (avg < 60)
            gLetter = "F";
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}

private void displaydata()
{
    try
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(studentName + "\t" + avg.ToString("N2") + "\t" + gLetter);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}

private void resetitems()
{
    openFile.FileName = " ";
}

private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: And why it should be different? In the _getdata_, you enter in a loop that reads each line until the end of file leaving the variables with the values of the last line. Then and only then, you start the processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that on method getData() you are reading allí lines to EOF, but you must add It to a lista or call t'he Other methods inside of the method because you are overriding the variables allí time and you only get the last line

Comment: Thank you! Adding the methods under the getdata() method worked. Now I feel silly lol.